# Me and some friends

Tags: riddle, rhyme, video-games

> I went out with friends, with ice and with flame.
>   We all play our parts, in a really fun game! 
>   But unlike those friends, I haven't a set name. 
>   Call me "whatevr", I'll work all the same.

Who am I?

#### Hints

1

> I don't exist IRL. Really, how lame! 
>  But you'll need to think video to win at my game. 
>  That "whatevr"s not a typo! Bet you're wondering why? 
>  It maxes at seven. So limited. Sigh.

2

> Still are you stuck? It's fine, I don't blame.
>  Of all my relation, you choose only my name.

3

> Back for more help? "I give up", you proclaim? 
>  Being "stuck to the floor" is the source of my fame!

4

> I'm your favorite thing. Now there's no excuse. 
>  Now go figure it out, you big silly goose :)

5

Now over two years, not a single one right. 
Let's bump with a hint, getting this back in your sight.

> I belong to a hero, be quite sure of that, 
>  I'm neither food or alive, not dog nor a cat. 
>  My name sticks with me, throughout all your trek 
>  but when we set off, you choose it, before a final recheck.

The earlier hints were unclear, their knowledge, a bit slurred. 
They've been tweaked and updated, given a total reword. 
I can't say much more, without giving it away. 
If this doesn't help, unsolved, this will stay.

Answer (score 5):

First attempt:

> the Name Rater.

I went out with friends, out with ice and flame.

> Ice and fire are types of Pokemon.

We all play our parts, in a really fun game!

> Pokemon!

But unlike those friends, I haven't a name.

> The Name Rater deosn't have an actual name.

Call me "whatevr", I'll work all the same.

> People can give him nicknames.

Hint 1

> I don't really exist. Really, how lame!
> $\to$He doesn't serve any gameplay uses, only aesthetic.
> But you'll need to think digitally to win at my game.
> $\to$Pokemon has a lot of numbers (stats, level, PP, HP, etc.)
> That name's not a typo, lest you thought that
> $\to$Your attempt to dispel typo-related answers.
> But now back to thinking, no more chitchat.

Hint 2

> Still are you stuck? It's fine, I don't blame.
> But fine, another hint: Of my friends, only I can rename.
> $\to$Once you assign a name to a Pokemon, only he can change it.

Hint 3

> Back for more help? Give up, do you claim?
> I'm stuck to the floor - it's the source of my fame.
> $\to$He can't leave his building.

Hint 4

> I'm your favorite thing. Now there's no excuse.
> $\to$He's the first person people look for if they made a typo/mistake when naming their Pokemon.
> Now figure figure it out, you big silly goose :)

Comment: Ooh, that's really good. Unfortunately, not the right answer :(

Comment: @MikeyT.K. Is it a specific game or games in general?

Comment: It is a specific game.